# Preventing focus during visual component construction in Java

Tags: java, focus, javax.imageio, jcomponent

I have created an application which requires the reloading of an image several times throughout the program execution. Perhaps it's clumsy, but my implementation was to extend the Component class in a subclass and reload the image via a fileName argument to it's constructor. The code is included below:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Grapher {

    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
    private static Graph graph = null;
    private static JScrollPane jsp = null;
public Grapher(){
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void display(String fileName) {
    if(jsp != null)
        frame.getContentPane().remove(jsp);
    graph = new Graph(fileName);
    jsp = new JScrollPane(graph);
    frame.getContentPane().add(jsp);
    frame.setSize(graph.getPreferredSize());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private class Graph extends Component{
    BufferedImage img;
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
    public Graph(String fileName) {
        setFocusable(false);
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {System.err.println("Error reading " + fileName);e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
}
```

Anyway, my problem is that whenever I call the `display` command this window steals the focus of everything java, including eclipse, which can be really agravating. I even tried adding `setFocusable(false)` in the constructor, but it still manages to steal the focus. How do I tell it to be focusable but not focus automatically with construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Perhaps it's clumsy, but my implementation was to extend the Component class in a subclass and reload the image via a fileName argument to it's constructor

There is no need for a custom component. Just use a JLabel and the setIcon(...) method when you want to change the image.

Even if you did need a custom component you would not extend Component, you would extend JComponent or JPanel in a Swing application.

Setting a frame visible automatically gives the frame focus. You can try using:

```
frame.setWindowFocusableState( false );
```

Then you might need to add a WindowListener to the frame. When the window is opened you can reset the focusable state to true.

Comment: Thank you for two useful pieces of information. 1. setVisible(true) steals the focus, and 2. JFrame is better.